# Windows Service Start-Up Error 1069

Tags: c#, windows, web-services

I am installing a new windows service coded in C# on a server. I installed the service fine on the server, but once i manually start up the service on a server, with the same login credentials that our other services use, i get the fatal error message notification:

"Could not start the %service name% on Local Computer. Error 1069: The Service did not start due to a logon failure."

I looked in the event log and i got a 7038 and 7000 event id error in that order.

**7038 event id message:**
"The %service name% service was unable to log on as %login% with the currently configured password due to the following error: 
Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.

To ensure that the service is configured properly, use the Services snap-in in Microsoft Management Console (MMC)."

**7000 event id message:**
"The %service name% service failed to start due to the following error: 
The service did not start due to a logon failure. "

I have other services that are using the same exact login account and they work fine. Is there something simple I could be missing?

Thanks

Comment: Does the service login have all the necessary privileges required by your new service?

Comment: Not sure, how do i find out the privledges information for that service account? The new service shouldnt require anything different than the ones already running anyway. I'm looking for this Microsoft Management Console snap-in but i can't find it. The OS that this server is running is Microsoft Windows Server 2003 Web Edition SP2 - if that helps any.

Comment: The snapin is services.msc; it should live in system32.

Not meant to be flippant, but are you sure you typed the userid and password correctly? Likewise, if the service login is a domain account, did you specify domain\login? That first message doesn't sound like permissions.

Comment: Wow. To get to the point, it was a bad password. I inherited all our projects without proper documentation. Thus the txt file i had on these logins, told me that the password was the same for this one service account across all our servers. Obviously it wasnt, as i just entered a password that was used for another account and it was working again. 

Thank you for your responses! They did help!

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, the MMC snapin you're looking for is just the Services applet in the Admin tools where you can change the username & password.

I always add a command line mode to any of the services that I write so that I can start them up manually and debug them, if you have something similar, try opening a command prompt using Run As to login as the service account user and then see if you can run it. If you don't have any way of running the service in non service mode you might want to consider adding something, it's quite easy and very useful when debugging.